# Google Play Promo Videos not getting displayed in Mobile but visible via Laptop Browser

Tags: youtube, google-play

Since Nov 2019, Google Play Promo Videos not getting displayed in Mobile but visible via Laptop Browser.

I checked a few other apps and in there the promo video is visible.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Its cause Google Play is preventing promo videos from being displayed if Ads are enabled on the video.

**Remove ads** for that specific video and **wait for 3 days** it will get enabled again in Google Play via Android Phones.

Comment: No man it's wrong. my video don't have any ads ! The thing is, On website of google playstore the video is visible but on mobile phones the video goes hidden after some days. This was a bug in playstore which google never fix.